# How to implement SOrtablerepository in Gedmo

Tags: symfony, doctrine

I would like to ask you how it si possible to implement the sortable repository for gedmo sortable extension into symfony 2. I  am a little confused how to inject the EntityManager and ClassMetadata into the constructor and how the repository register correctly in services.yml and entity.

Here is the repository:
https://github.com/l3pp4rd/DoctrineExtensions/blob/master/lib/Gedmo/Sortable/Entity/Repository/SortableRepository.php

Thank you very much!

Comment: You want enable sortable bechavior?

Comment: Try the Symfony bundle instead of the base code - https://github.com/stof/StofDoctrineExtensionsBundle

Answer (score 2):

I recommend you install the [StofDoctrineExtensionsBundle](https://github.com/stof/StofDoctrineExtensionsBundle)

And you can enable the sortable behavior in your config file.

Example:

**config.yml**

```
stof_doctrine_extensions:
    orm:
        default:
            sortable: true
```

**Entity class**

```
/**
 * Acme\Bundle\ProjectBundle\Entity\Foo
 *
 * @ORM\Table
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Gedmo\Sortable\Entity\Repository\SortableRepository")
 */
class Foo
{
    /**
     * @var integer $position
     *
     * @Gedmo\SortablePosition
     * @ORM\Column(name="position", type="integer")
     */
    private $position;
}
```

Comment: Sure, I understand, But I need sort a tree structure and I have already a repository which ingerits from Gedmo TreeRepository.

Answer (score 0):

Remember to subscribe GedmoListener on boot()

```
<?php

class AcmeBundle extends Bundle
{
    $em = $this->container->get('doctrine.orm.default_entity_manager');
    $evm = $em->geteventmanager();
    $evm->addeventsubscriber(new \gedmo\sortable\sortablelistener);
}
```